# Is it possible to export Selenium IDE test cases as Java/ TestNG/ WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng, selenium-ide, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium IDE 1.9.0 there are options to export testcases as Java / JUnit4 / Webdriver and Java / TestNG / Remote Control (along with many more options).

I want to know is there any way to export the test case as Java / TestNG /Webdriver? If not is there any workaround for the same? Or can we export it as JUnit and change it to TestNG in some simple steps??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to do that!

Workaround:

Export it as Java JUnit4 Webdriver and just change the imports and annotations.

Thats all you need to do

Comment: Yes, exactly. After exporting as Java JUnit4 Webdriver, it needs some modification. After that, it's ready to execute in TestNG

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is not possible to export the Selenese scripts from IDE to Java/ TestNG/ WebDriver.
But, you can edit the scripts and run on TestNG. It works!!

For alternate solution, make use of **Selenium Builder** from Sauce for this combination
https://saucelabs.com/builder

Answer (score 0):

If you must use the Selenium IDE then you'll have to export as Java JUnit4 Webdriver and change the imports and annotations, but don't do that...

Use Saucebuilder.  It's a far better tool than the Selenium IDE mostly because it properly understands the difference between the Selenium 1 API and the Selenium 2 API, and, well it works.  Sure the UI is clunky, but I'll take a clunky UI over hacking the output of a tool that kinda-sorta-works every time.  Here's the link...

https://saucelabs.com/builder