# Import Selenium scripts to WebDriver

Tags: selenium-ide, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to import/use scripts which has been generated in Firefox's Selenium-IDE plugin into Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: there is here a way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258712/is-it-possible-to-export-selenium-ide-test-cases-as-java-testng-webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no automatic way to import Selenium's data into WebDriver. I'm going to write a convertor myself.

Thank you all any way :)

Answer (score 3):

In Selenium IDE, open the test case you wish to export to Webdriver
From the Selenium IDE File menu, select "Export Test Case As..." and select the variant which matches your webdriver configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a 'Export Test Case' (if exporting a single test case) option in the File menu of the IDE. This will have the languages it can be exported to.

Comment: Thanks but my question is how to import IDE's scripts into WebDriver!

Comment: That is how you do it....unless you mean the other way around in which case it is not possible. Selenium IDE tests cases are converted into Selenium Web Driver test cases by exporting them into the language you want (C#/Ruby/Java/PHP).

Comment: I thought that there is way which WebDriver can read Selenium IDE's scripts and it seems that there is no easy way, does it? :(

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You've got some IDE scripts yes? What language of the WebDriver are you trying to use?

Comment: Yes, I've got scripts from the IDE and now instead of programming I'd like WebDriver to read and run the scripts!

Comment: I think you are confusing what the WebDriver does. It does not read scripts from the IDE. It is just a third party library you code against. This is why there is an Export option. It will export the IDE scripts into a large section of code that the WebDriver can read, depending on what language you are using.

Comment: _It will export the IDE scripts into a large section of code that the WebDriver can read_ OK! How can I do this?!

Answer (score 1):

I think what he wants is for there to be a way to "drive" and control IDE scripts from a third party application.  There is no way to do this as far as I know.  Actually, it would be useful to do this because IDE scripts cannot setup data or act conditionally very well.  On the other hand, general purpose programming languages are much better at performing these tasks but aren't very suited to actually performing the browser manipulation.  Plus, exporting the scripts every time there is a change can be very labor intensive.